# Identificar o fim da pagina no scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web

Primeiramente desculpe, vi que tem outras perguntas semelhantes mas estou tendo um erro que estou faz 24h tentando solucionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima mostra um metodo que '' tenta detectar o fim da pagina'' e depois faz o ajax carregando novos produtos.

Com relação ao ajax e carregar os produtos esta tudo OK, porque realizei um teste com um button. Mas toda vez ficar clicando não da muito certo.

Minha aplicacão é mvc com bootstrap 4.
O que está me tirando do sério é que não sei como mais descobrir ou tentar o porque de SEMPRE o totalheight é menor que o scrollheight, a diferença e minima mas assim ele não entra na condição pra rodar o ajax.

O body no css esta com 100% height.

Ja tentei outras formas e não consegui. alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar isso?
Obrigado!

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        toastr.success('Produto Carregados!');

        window.onscroll = function ()
        {
            var scrollHeight, totalHeight;
            scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
            totalHeight = window.scrollY + window.outerHeight;

            if (totalHeight === scrollHeight)

            {
                jQuery('#progress').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ProdutosMercado/ListaProdutosInicial',
                    data: { 'page': pagina },
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.length > 10) {
                            var div = document.getElementById('produtoscontainer');
                            div.innerHTML += data;
                            pagina++;
                            toastr.success('Produto Carregados!')
                        }
                        else
                            toastr.warning('Não há mais produtos!')

                        jQuery('#progress').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta colocando o código, não os prints. E dê uma lida no [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/21112)

Comment: Vou atualizar minha pergunta. Me desculpe.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que se adicionar este código para verificar o fim da pagina, fique melhor:

Substitua o console.log pelo seu codigo ajax

```
 var timer = null;


        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            const faltante = 50

            if (timer !== null) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    if (window.scrollMaxY-faltante < window.scrollY) {
                       console.log('tste3')
                    }
            }, 30);
        }, false);
```

Comment: Ele dispara o evento, mas dispara 2 vezes quando chega no fim da pagina, fazendo carregar errado os eventos. =/

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, teste novamente, fazendo favor.

Comment: Coloquei no document.ready e nada =/

Comment: não precisa ser no document.ready